# What is the origin of "daemon" with regards to computing?

Tags: etymology, terminology

*Daemon* has an interesting usage in computing. From my local dictionary:

> a background process that handles requests for services such as print spooling and file transfers, and is dormant when not required

Does anyone know where this came from? I assume its relation to the word *demon* is notable. My dictionary also lists *daemon* as an archaic form of *demon*. Why did computing use *daemon* instead of *demon*?

Comment: I had always ascribed this to the high correlation between Linux programmers and D&D players.

Comment: I find it highly coincidental that this question has been posed so soon after [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/i7yd7/the_origin_of_the_word_daemon/) was posted to the r/programming reddit (and is currently at the very top of my homepage)

Comment: @TJ Ellis: I don't follow reddit, but I do follow Hacker News, and [this](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2691752) appeared at around the same time.

Comment: must just be the zeitgeist :)

Comment: Its association with computing goes back to the "[Pandaemonium architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemonium_architecture)" in perceptual research. In this model there are multiple extremely stupid daemons, each searching for one thing -- a corner, a fricative, some alcohol vapor -- that yell when they find it. The more they find, the louder they yell. Loudest daemon defines the sensation. Very primitive stuff, but it works.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In this [interesting history](http://ei.cs.vt.edu/%7Ehistory/Daemon.html), which is the actual description of the origin of this use from Professor Corbato, he explains that *daemon* originally had the connotation of "*an attendant ... or indwelling spirit*" and that:

> By the late 16th century, the general supernatural meaning was being distinguished with the spelling daemon, while the evil meaning remained with demon.

He goes on to share the story of Maxwell's daemon.  Maxwell was a 19th century scientist who'd posed a physics problem in which a tiny daemon was the attendant at a gate between two chambers that was large enough for a single molecule to enter.  The daemon observed the molecules and chose which ones to allow to pass through the gate.

So now we come to the crux of it. We have established a daemon as an attendant, and a scientist used a hypothetical daemon in a famous problem in which the daemon's job was to monitor molecular movement.  Professor Corbato wraps up his explanation with

> As you probably know, the "system processes" called daemons monitor other tasks and perform predetermined actions depending on their behavior. This is so reminiscent of Maxwell's daemon watching his molecules that we can only assume that whoever dubbed these "system processes" had Maxwell's daemon in mind.

The history also notes that Professor Saltzer, who also worked on Project MAC with Professor Corbato at the time "daemon" came into use for this purpose, confirms that this is the origin of *daemon* as it is used in computing.

Comment: Maxwell's daemon was my first thought here for a "tireless / reliable automated attendant", so I was a bit surprised to see from [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Maxwell%27s+daemon%2CMaxwell%27s+demon&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMaxwell%20%27s%20daemon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMaxwell%20%27s%20demon%3B%2Cc0) that even *that* one is almost always spelt ***demon***. It's ***always*** a daemon in my Linux-based computer system.

Answer (score 16):

> According to Fernando J. Corbato who
> worked on Project MAC in 1963 his team
> is the first to use the term daemon.
> The use of the term daemon was
> inspired by Maxwell's daemon, in
> physics and thermodynamics as an
> imaginary agent which helped to sort
> molecules.
>
> "We fancifully began to use the word
> daemon to describe background
> processes which worked tirelessly to
> perform system chores."
>
> (...)
>
> In the Unix System Administration
> Handbook, Evi Nemeth states the
> following about daemons:
>
> "Many people equate the word "daemon" with the word "demon",
> implying some kind of satanic
> connection between UNIX and the
> underworld. This is an egregious
> misunderstanding. "Daemon" is actually
> a much older form of "demon"; daemons
> have no particular bias towards good
> or evil, but rather serve to help
> define a person's character or
> personality. The ancient Greeks'
> concept of a "personal daemon" was
> similar to the modern concept of a
> "guardian angel"—eudaemonia is the
> state of being helped or protected by
> a kindly spirit. As a rule, UNIX
> systems seem to be infested with both
> daemons and demons."

See a full explanation in the [Daemon (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29#Etymology) Wikipedia article.

Comment: This explains what the word means, but how did it become associated with computing? Namely, if it was inspired by Maxwell's daemon, what was Maxwell's daemon?

Comment: @MrHen Project MAC was a Project on Mathematics and Computation, a collaborative computer endeavour in the 1960s that sought to to create a functional time-sharing system. --*what was Maxwell's daemon?* - From the answer *an imaginary agent which helped to sort molecules.*

Answer (score -3):

According to https://kb.iu.edu/d/aiau, "Daemon" stands for Disk and Execution Monitor.

More information on this meaning here:
[www.techopedia.com: Disk and Execution Monitor (Daemon)](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3347/disk-and-execution-monitor-daemon)

Extract:
**What Does Disk and Execution Monitor (Daemon) Mean?**

A disk and execution monitor (daemon) is a background process run in computer multitasking operating systems, usually at bootstrap time, to perform administrative changes or monitor services.

Common daemon processes include email handlers, print spoolers and other programs that perform OS administrative tasks. Daemons also perform specified operations at predefined times in response to events.

Comment: Your link doesn't cite any sources, while the [jargon file](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/daemon.html) not only disagrees but gives some history. The jargon file at least has some pedigree when it comes to documenting Unix/hacker culture.

Comment: The entry for _daemon_ in _The New Hacker's Dictionary, third edition (1996), begins this way: "**daemon** _n._ {from the mythological meaning, later rationalized as the acronym 'Disk And Execution MONitor'} ..."Programmers seem peculiarly susceptible to rationalizing as acronyms computer terms whose origin they don't know.